# function param issue in Scala 11, works in Scala 12 using resilience4j

Tags: java, scala, resilience4j

I would have a Scala question. I have the following code while using resilience4j library. The code works like a charm in Scala 12, but my project, a client library uses Scala-Cross compiling to Scala 11 also. When building it under Scala 11 I get the following error. Anyone has an idea how this should be written in Scala 11 to also compile?

```
import io.github.resilience4j.retry.Retry
import java.util.function.{Supplier, Function => JavaFunction}
val supplier: Supplier[List[Endpoint]] = () => getEndpoints
val decoratedSupplier = Retry.decorateSupplier(retry, supplier)
val result = io.vavr.control.Try.ofSupplier(decoratedSupplier)
  .onSuccess { endpoints => endpoints }
    .onFailure { failure =>
      // handle failure
    }.get()
```

In Scala 11 I get the following errors:

```
[Error] ServiceDiscoveryClient.scala:38: type mismatch;
 found   : () => List[Endpoint]
 required: java.util.function.Supplier[List[Endpoint]]
[Error] ServiceDiscoveryClient.scala:41: missing parameter type
[Error] ServiceDiscoveryClient.scala:97: type mismatch;
 found   : () => List[Endpoint]
 required: java.util.function.Supplier[List[Endpoint]]
four errors found
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: An idea to use scala library instead of a java one: https://github.com/cb372/cats-retry

Comment: Scala 11 or 12 don't exist

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.11 you need `-Xexperimental` compiler option to support passing lambdas as SAM types such as `java.util.function.Supplier`. In 2.12 it's enabled by default. You can either add this option, or add [`scala-java8-compat`](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) dependency and

```
import scala.compat.java8.FunctionConverters._

...
val supplier: Supplier[List[Endpoint]] = (() => getEndpoints).asJava
```

(`asJava` may also be needed for lambdas used in `result`).

Comment: hey, thanks! I tried both suggestions but seems that nothing changes:

I still get:  
```[Error] ServiceDiscoveryClient.scala:38: missing parameter type
[Error] ServiceDiscoveryClient.scala:94: type mismatch;
 found   : () => List[Endpoint]
 required: java.util.function.Supplier[List[Endpoint]]
two errors found```

any ideas? I use: ```    implementation "org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat${scalaSuffix}:0.9.0" ```

Comment: In the question you had `four errors found`, in this message `two errors found`. Maybe you have another place to change?

Comment: In the first one was the same, I just commented out the other 2 to give here a better code example. Nothing changed by adding the change you mentioned.

Comment: If you use `asJava` I really don't see how `found : () => List[Endpoint]` is possible. You can also be more explicit about which Java type you need and write `asJavaSupplier(() => getEndpoints)`.

Comment: Basically, see the tests here https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/test/scala/scala/compat/java8/FunctionConvertersTest.scala.

Comment: I am using gradle as build tool, was wondering if that can be anyhow related. Will check the docs for: `scala-java8-compat` if there is anything special to do for gradle support. 
I will next try out your 2nd suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Hey, got it working now. Having a similar one now for EventConsumer but I guess I can fix it with the same approach, thanks! will check it out